# Could a negatively charged nucleus have caused the results in the Rutherford scattering experiment?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

Struggling to understand the answer to this question.

> When alpha particles are directed at a thin gold foil it is found that most of the alpha
>   particles go straight through undeflected. However a very small number are scattered
>   through angles greater than 90°.
>
> Which of the following is not a valid conclusion?
>
> 1. The atom is mainly empty space.
> 2. The nucleus must be positively charged.
> 3. The nucleus must contain most of the mass of the atom.
> 4. There is a large charge concentration in the centre of the atom.

The answer is 2. I assumed that a negative nucleus would not scatter alpha particles in this way. Could it?

Comment: I am not sure that (3) is a valid conclusion either - unless you make other assumptions about things that you know about the atom.

Comment: @sammygerbil No he's not. He's asking if the differential scattering cross-section (the thing the Geiger-Marsden experiment measured) between like charged particles is different from that between unlike charged particles.

Comment: @dmckee Yes, thanks. I read the final question too literally, and out of context. I have edited the question.

Comment: (3) is indeed a valid conclusion. To backscatter requires that the mass of the atom is concentrated, and if not in the nucleus where?

Comment: Thank you, I can see now that its a duplicate question!. So how does an attractive force cause scattering of greater than 90 degrees? Surely thats repulsion?

Comment: @JonCuster - I would argue that your comment requires you to know that there is a nucleus, in other words, that there is some known structure of the atom. If atoms were comprised of two equal and oppositely charged particles that orbit each other, the scattering result might be the same. And then neither (3) nor (4) would be proven.

Comment: @johnsmith4725 - consider a comet’s path around the sun. It goes around the backside, rather the repelling off the front side (so to speak). The math all works out the same, the trajectory is just a bit different in the two cases.

Comment: @Floris - assuming the two parts were roughly equal mass, it would have taken a bit more time to sort it out, but the kinematics show the large mass assymetry between the alpha and what it bounced off of. As an aside, one of the early models for deuterium tried to figure out how to get a proton-electron pair into the nucleus.

Comment: @JonCuster gold is heavy enough that you would still get scatter through more than 90 degrees if the mass was split. I am simply arguing that the question was poorly worded.

Comment: Yes, it would still scatter. Clarifying the nuclear structure would then wait for measurements of the backscattered energy, not just angle. That did not take long at all, although is glossed over or outright ignored in standard physics textbooks. Us folks who still do ion scattering are more conscious of it.

Comment: @johnsmith4725 Your question is a duplicate, although the answers to [Rutherford alpha scattering?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110959) did not actually address the issue which entrop-x picked up on. I have added an answer which depicts how this comes about.

Answer (score 5):

The Coulomb scattering angular dependence is independent of the sign of the charge.  It goes as $(Z_1 Z_2)^2$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering for instance.

Comment: Indeed, which is why you can use the Rutherford formula for gravitational scattering as well (with appropriate adjustments for the different constants in the potential definitions).

Comment: This is correct! But it doesn't answer the question which of the four statements in the question is not valid.

Comment: @freecharly: of course it answers the question: if the scattering is the same for positive and negative nucleae, then the scattering observed cannot prove that the scatter center was positive.  Because if it were negative the same result would have been obtained, so the result doesn't help you saying whether it is positive or negative.

Comment: @entrop-x - You are, of course right! The explicit conclusion that statement 2. is thus incorrect was only missing in your answer.

Comment: In principle the full $\alpha + \mathrm{Au}$ interaction includes the nuclear force (that is it is not just the Coulomb force) in the attractive case and will be slightly different for repulsive and attractive forces for small impact parameters. In practice, I doubt the Geiger-Marsden apparatus had the sensitivity to detect the difference.